# Searching for Dates in Column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search for a date in a column in VBA.  I have verified that the value exists within the column and I have also formatted the date to be that of the dates in the reference column.  Have been scratching my head and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.  I've seen several questions related to this, and I have even mirrored one of the solutions, which has not worked.

Notes:
1) All dates are stored in column 1 (A) 2) Date format is "m/d/yyyy" 3) Sheet 13 is where the range lives 4) I also have a named range that contains the date i'm searching for and I access that range by referencing the cell rather than the named range since VBA doesn't seem to like that.  Any thoughts?

```
    searchString = Format(Sheet3.Cells(5, 4).Value, "m/d/yyyy")

    With Sheet13.Range("A:A")

        Set searchCell = .Find(What:=CDate(searchString), After:=ActiveCell, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    End With
```

Comment: Are your dates in Sheet13.Range("A:A") stored as dates or text.  Excel dates are actually numbers, not text.   You seem to be trying a text match with a date field.

Comment: Try:  `After:= .Cells(1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the date (stored as number value in Excel):

```
Dim DateVal As Date

DateVal = Sheet3.Cells(5, 4).Value

With Sheet13.Range("A:A")
    Set searchCell = .Find(What:=DateVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
End With
```

Comment: Shai Rado the solution above throws a type mismatch exception when trying to execute the find statement.

Comment: @StormsEdge did you define `Dim searchCell  as Range` ?

Comment: Yes.  searchCell is a range and searchString is a date.  It was a string when I first started.  Neither appear to work

Answer (score 0):

Another example of how using references like `ActiveAnything` can lead to errors.

In your code, if `ActiveCell` doesn't happen to be in sheet13 column A, your code will error.

Change to `After:=.Cells(1,1)` or something similar so you ensure you are starting with some cell within in the column you are using as the SearchRange.